# How to get nullable Constraints with Grails 2.0?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I'm using grails 2.0 with mysql and i want some Domain attributes to be nullable.
In my domain class i did:

```
static constraints = {
    counter(nullable: true)
    competitors(nullable: true)
}
```

After starting my grails app, it creates the correspondending sql but in my mysql table, the attributes aren't nullable, they're "NOT  NULL".

```
CREATE TABLE `lookup_query` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `competitors` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `counter` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Why are my mysql-attributes "NOT NULL" and not "NULL" ? I want them to be "NULL". Where is my mistake?

Comment: Drop table `lookup_query` in MySQL and run Grails 2.0 again to make sure that table is recreated during application start. If table fields are still NOT NULL please share your whole LookupQuery domain class code.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm getting closer to the problem. Hibernate doesn't make Long attributes in database nullable. With Strings everything works fine but with Long attributes hibernate doesn't make them nullable in database...is this a hibernate bug?

Comment: make sure you have declared `Long competitors` not `long competitors`.

Comment: Yeah! It works! It has to be "Long" and not "long". It also has to be "Float" and not "float" ;-) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the boxed vs. unboxed types. A boxed type is a class and hence can be a null reference, while an unboxed type is a "primitive" and cannot hold a null value. GORM recognizes this and knows that you simply can't have a null value for a primitive type so it does not allow the columns in the DB to be null (even though your `constraints` block might allow it) since it knows that it isn't possible in the code.

If you want a field to be nullable, your code has to allow it to be so in order for the database to be created that way.

Another option is to change the GORM default from `nullable: false` to `nullable: true` for all columns.